# ControlTemplate Binding to Attached DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am creating a `ControlTemplate` for a `ContentControl` that displays a bordered `TextBox` with a background that could be coloured.  I have created an attached property to hold a property that defines whether to show the background.  I cannot seem to get the syntax correct to bind to the attached property to the `Visibility` property of an element in the template.

The attached property is:

```
public static class AttachedPropertyExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty 
        BackgroundVisible = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BackgroundVisible", 
            typeof(Visibility), 
            typeof(AttachedPropertyExtensions), 
            new PropertyMetadata(default(Visibility)));

    public static void SetBackgroundVisible(UIElement element, Visibility value)
    {
        element.SetValue(BackgroundVisible, value);
    }

    public static Visibility GetBackgroundVisible(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Visibility)element.GetValue(BackgroundVisible);
    }
}
```

The `ControlTemplate`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="BorderedTextBlock" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Grid Margin="{StaticResource TextControlMarginThemeThickness}"
          BorderBrush="{StaticResource TextBoxBorderThemeBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{StaticResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}">
        <Border x:Name="backgroundBorder"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                Visibility="{Binding Path=con:AttachedPropertiesExtensions.BackgroundVisible, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}" />

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" 
                      VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ContentPresenter Height="80" 
                              TextWrapping="Wrap"
                              Margin="{StaticResource TextControlThemePadding}" />
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And these are used using:

```
<UserControl ...
             xmlns:con="using:Scanners.Tetra.UWPmvvm.Helpers">
...
    <ContentControl x:Name="lblReturnText" 
                    Template="{StaticResource BorderedTextBlock}" 
                    Content="{Binding ReturnText}" 
                    Background="#DDDDDD" 
                    con:AttachedPropertyExtensions.BackgroundVisible="{Binding ReturnText, Converter={StaticResource HasContentConverter}}" />
    <ContentControl x:Name="lblErrorText" 
                    Template="{StaticResource BorderedTextBlock}" 
                    Content="{Binding ErrorText}" 
                    Background="#C03556" 
                    con:AttachedPropertyExtensions.BackgroundVisible="{Binding ErrorText, Converter={StaticResource HasContentConverter}}" />
</UserControl>
```

HasContentConverter:

```
class HasContentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        string val = (string)value;
        string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else
        {
            return Visibility.Collapsed
        }
    ...
```

When the application is run (being deployed on a ARM mobile device),  the follow error is displayed in the Output

```
Error: BindingExpression path error: 'con:AttachedPropertiesExtensions' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl'. BindingExpression: Path='con:AttachedPropertiesExtensions.BackgroundVisible' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Border' (Name='backgroundBorder'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
```

When I change

```
Path=con:AttachedPropertiesExtensions.BackgroundVisible
```

to

```
Path=(con:AttachedPropertiesExtensions.BackgroundVisible)
```

(or anything with brackets) I get a error when building over the entire `ControlTemplate`:

```
The text associated with this error code could not be found.
E_UNKNOWN_ERROR
```

How do I set bind to the property?

Comment: First, name the static readonly field correctly: `public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundVisibleProperty = ....`

Comment: ok, but the attached property seems to work on the `ContentControl`: A break point in `HasContentConverter` successfully breaks and there are no messages in the output from then.  Only when used in the binding to `Visibility` on the border in the actual template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test UWP here because we're still on Win7, but in WPF, your attached property definition is fine, including the name. Looks like I was wrong about that part. I'd still rename it just to follow convention, but WPF doesn't care. Maybe UWP does -- I'd make sure.

What was broken for me, testing your code, was just the binding path. It needs parens around the `Path`, because it's an attached property, and they have complicated names that don't follow C# property naming conventions:

```
Visibility="{Binding (con:AttachedPropertyExtensions.BackgroundVisible), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
```

The parens around the `Path` tell it that the whole string indicates one single elaborate property name, so it goes to `con:AttachedPropertyExtensions.BackgroundVisible` for the `DependencyProperty` definition field. Otherwise, it thinks `con:AttachedPropertyExtensions` is supposed to be a property of the templated parent, which has a property of its own named `BackgroundVisible`. But that doesn't even make sense. Even if this weren't a syntax error:

```
public Visibility con:AttachedPropertyExtensions{ get; set; }
```

...it's not what you're trying to communicate here.

If I add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to your original `Binding`, here's the part of the debug trace output where it fails:

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=4917414):   At level 0 - for ContentControl.con:AttachedPropertyExtensions found accessor <null>
>
> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'con:AttachedPropertyExtensions' property not found on 'object' ''ContentControl' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=con:AttachedPropertyExtensions.BackgroundVisibility; DataItem='ContentControl' (Name=''); target element is 'Border' (Name=''); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
>
> System.Windows.Data Warning: 103 : BindingExpression (hash=4917414): Replace item at level 1 with {NullDataItem}

Comment: Hmm.  I had tried that but Visual Studio threw a `E_UNKNOWN_ERROR` error on build.  I have just tried again having closed Visual Studio over lunch, and it worked this time.  My guess is it was VS getting confused (which it seems to do quite a bit with UWP).  Thanks

Comment: @JonathanTwite Since 2008 or so, Visual Studio gets more easily confused with every release.